# Command "npm install" exited with 1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules, package.json

`npm ERR! code ERESOLVE`

`npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve`

`npm ERR!`

`npm ERR! While resolving: radium@0.26.2`

`npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0`

`npm ERR! node_modules/react`

`npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project`

`npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0`

`npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom`

`npm ERR!     react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project`

`npm ERR!   1 more (react-icons)`

`npm ERR!`

`npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:`

`npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from radium@0.26.2`

`npm ERR! node_modules/radium`

`npm ERR!   radium@"^0.26.2" from the root project`

`npm ERR!`

`npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2`

`npm ERR! node_modules/react`

`npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from radium@0.26.2`

`npm ERR!   node_modules/radium`

`npm ERR!     radium@"^0.26.2" from the root project`

`npm ERR!`

`npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry`

`npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps`

`npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.`

`npm ERR!`

`npm ERR!`

`npm ERR! For a full report see:`

`npm ERR! /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-08-22T11_11_53_352Z-eresolve-report.txt`

`npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:`

`npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-08-22T11_11_53_352Z-debug-0.log`

`Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1`

and my package.json like this:

```
{


"name": "portfolio",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-typed": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.15",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.28",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

can anyone help? what is the source and reason of the error and what should i do i don't understand anything

Comment: Try to re-install the node. some package are not compatible with your Node

Answer (score 0):

Check NPM and Node version

```
node -v
npm -v
```

if node found try to install it
set registry

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
```

Clean cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

then again try to install it

```
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```